# Multi-step form in React + Formik

Tags: react.js, form, jsx

I did a multi-step form. I only learn how to build applications, and would like you to check my code out, whether everything is done well, and so on. PropTypes checking was not implemented intentionally to make the code a bit cleaner.
What would you recommend me to re-do or change up?
The full-on version is available on GitHub: https://github.com/AlexKor-5/FormChallenge/tree/337e807525cc7d33a6b4c10abb0d02c3dc25a64e

There is my basic file:

````
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Step1 } from './pages/Step1/Step1'
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import { MainContainer } from './components/MainContainer/MainContainer'
import 'yup-phone'
import { Step2 } from './pages/Step2/Step2'
import { Step3 } from './pages/Step3/Step3'
import { Overview } from './pages/Overview/Overview'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

export const App = () => {
    const [haveNumber, setHaveNumber] = useState(false)
    return (
        <>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: '',
                    email: '',
                    phoneNumber: '',
                    availablePhoneNumber: false,
                    files: [],
                }}
                validationSchema={Yup.object({
                    firstName: Yup.string()
                        .min(2, 'Have to be at least two characters')
                        .max(15, 'Have to be 15 characters or less')
                        .required('Required'),
                    lastName: Yup.string()
                        .max(20, 'Have to be 20 or less characters')
                        .required('Required'),
                    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid Email').required('Required.'),
                    phoneNumber: haveNumber
                        ? Yup.string().phone('UA', false, 'Phone number is invalid')
                        : Yup.string(),
                })}
                onSubmit={async values => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(values))
                    const response = await fetch('/overview', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(values),
                    })
                    if (response.ok) {
                        Swal.fire('Good job!', '', 'success').then(data => data)
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire('Something went wrong!', '', 'error').then(data => data)
                    }
                }}
            >
                <Form>
                    <MainContainer>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" element={<Step1 />} />
                            <Route path="step2" element={<Step2 setHaveNumber={setHaveNumber} />} />
                            <Route path="step3" element={<Step3 />} />
                            <Route path="overview" element={<Overview />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </MainContainer>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
        </>
    )
}
```
````